# possible alternative to LIKE clause in specific situation

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sql-like

I have a web service which returns results to a jquery auto-complete.

For the query I must use four full blown like clauses

```
LIKE('%SOME_TERM%')
```

The reason being that the users need to be able to return results from sub strings as well as proper words. I have also tried full-text indexes with their many options in this case in both Natural and Boolean mode but they just does not work as well and their results leave a lot to be desired in this case.

The database is highly optimized with indexes and even with the LIKE clauses returning results from a query with multiple joins and with one of the tables having 200,000 rows takes ~ 0.2/0.3 seconds on first run. Once its cached by the server then obviously the time taken is miniscule.

I was wondering if there is anything else that would be worth trying here. I had looked at some standalone search providers but I'm a little tight time-wise on this project(nearly done and ready to launch) so can't afford any large setups or large-scale refactoring time and funding wise.

Its possible that it's as good as it gets but no harm in letting SO have its say is my attitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think apache solr is they way to go for you. For full text searches.
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

But like you said, if you don't have much time left, and you are sure your queries are performing at their best. I don't see much you can do.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing myself. I had looked into Solr but its excess to requirements in this case I reckon. Thanks for the advice. All the best.